# Setting RDATA Flags Field of a DNSKEY RR

Tags: dns, rfc

I've been referring to RFC 4034 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034#page-4), but there is something I quite don't understand about the flags field of a RDATA for a DNSKEY RR.

As stated in the RFC 2.1.1. The Flags Field, "Bits 0-6 and 8-14 are reserved: these bits MUST have value 0 upon creation of the DNSKEY RR and MUST be ignored upon receipt.".

But few lines under in 2.2. The DNSKEY RR Presentation Format, it states "The Flag field MUST be represented as an unsigned decimal integer. Given the currently defined flags, the possible values are: 0, 256, and 257."

How can bits 8-14 be required to have value of 0 if using 256 and 257 as the section value ?

Could someone explain to me if there is something I don't get please ?

I am currently building my own DNS server and I need to validate the format of a DNSKEY RR as well as craft packets on demand for them.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently building my own DNS server

I hope it is mostly for learning, because otherwise this is a tricky matter!
You can (should) also study existing DNS libraries to understand implementation details.

As for the values, let us go back to the fields representation:

```
                        1 1 1 1 1 1 
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |              Flags            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0| => 256 (ZSK case)
   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1| => 1 (SEP case)
   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1| => 257 (KSK case)
```

Bits 8-14 are always 0, as are the 0-6 ones.
`SEP` alone can't happen, so value 1 is not possible, 256 and 257 are the usual one for DNSSEC, and 0 (which means bit 7 is 0 so a key but "not DNSSEC case").

Remember that most (all?) of IETF protocols are MSB, left-most bit is most significant, so bit 15 is 2⁰, bit 14 is 2¹, etc. from right to left up to bit 0 at left which encodes 2¹⁵.

You can find that repeated in RFC 1035 §2.3.2:

> Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity, the left most bit in
> the diagram is the high order or most significant bit.
>
> [..]
>
> Similarly, whenever a multi-octet field represents a numeric quantity the left most bit of the whole field is the most significant bit. When a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet is transmitted first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Things a way more clear now !